Issues Running Jitsi Docker Setup (Failed to get a successful response, giving up)
When I am setting up jitsi meet (docker) on my centOS server, its gives "You have been disconnected.
You might want to check your network connection. Reconnecting in xx seconds..." on the UI and in the console it shows "Failed to get a successful response, giving up."
Attaching screenshot

